# JQuery valHooks: select by attribute?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

JQuery Valhooks are either limited in their applicability, or they are very poorly documented.

I was using valhooks by setting a type value on a select2 element (select2 is a fanciful way of handling select lists):

```
$("#mySelect").select2();
$("#mySelect").select2('container')[0].type='select2Marker';

$.valHooks['select2Marker'] = {
    get: function (el) {
        alert("hello there");
    },
}
```

The problem is if I trigger a change in the select2 list, the type attribute gets wiped out.

```
$("#mySelect").select2().trigger("change");
```

I figured I could resolve this by putting a special class or even a custom "data-select2type" attribute on my select tag but I can't figure out how to define valhooks to select by an attribute or class. For example,

```
$.valHooks[".my-class"] = {...}
```

doesn't work when I try to add the class "my-class" to my select list. Is this possible? What are the different ways valHooks can be attached to a node?

Comment: Should `select2Val` be `select2Marker`? Your `get:` function needs to return something.

Comment: Whoops- thanks, I'll fix that now. the Get function does need to return something, but it should also make it inside regardless of the existence of a return, which it does not

Comment: `valHooks` doesn't look at custom attributes. The code is: `hooks = jQuery.valHooks[ elem.type ] || jQuery.valHooks[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() ];`

Comment: So IOW, only the element type attribute and the element name can be considered? Why have that restriction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

valHooks can only be attached to an input type or node name. Since custom types don't stick on non-input elements, attach the hook to the node name. Then test whether it has the class you want to customize.

```
$.valHooks['div'] = {
    get: function(el) {
        if ($(el).hasClass("myClass"))
            alert("hello there");
            return ...;
        },
    set: ...
};
```

Comment: Barmar, I'm trying to set the "type" property on the dom element, not an attribute on a node.. and I can do this successfully until the change trigger

Comment: yeah, this won't work, because jQuery uses `elem.type`, not `elem.getAttribute('type')`.

Comment: The problem is that only `<input>` elements can have a `type` property.

Comment: Came up with a clunky solution.